# Pandas dataframe duplicates - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

I have a simplified dataframe like this:

```
 ID  RecordingType Date                 Value
 1   FEVR          2019-05-22 18:37:10  1.36
 1   FEVR          2019-05-22 18:41:12  1.35
 1   FEVR          2019-05-22 18:45:16  1.35
```

I am trying to run this code:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'RecordingType', 'Date'], ascending=True).reset_index().drop(columns=["index"])
df["ToRemove"] = False
dict_temp_df = df.to_dict("records")

outputcolnames = {'FEVR':'Value'}

for i in range(df.shape[0]-1):

curr_recording_type = df[i]["RecordingType"]
next_recording_type = df[i+1]["RecordingType"]
        
# Check if current and next row have the same ID and RecordingType and the difference in time between the current and next rows is less than 60 minutes
        
if dict_temp_df[i]["ID"] == dict_temp_df[i+1]["ID"] and curr_recording_type == next_recording_type and abs((dict_temp_df[i]["Date"] - dict_temp_df[i+1]["Date"]).total_seconds() / 60) < 60:
          
    # For similar rows the first row is marked for deletion and the second row's value is updated depending on the Recording Type
                
    df.at[i,"ToRemove"] = True
                
    if curr_recording_type == 'FEVR':

        df.at[i+1,outputcolnames[next_recording_type]] = max(dict_temp_df[i][outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]], dict_temp_df[i+1][outputcolnames[next_recording_type]])
                    
    else:
           
        df.at[i+1,outputcolnames[next_recording_type]] += dict_temp_df[i][outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]]

# Remove the columns to be deleted
df = df[df["ToRemove"] == False].reset_index().drop(columns=["index"])
```

The desired output should have the last consecutive row of these duplicates updated with the max value of these rows like this:

```
 ID  RecordingType Date                 Value
 1   FEVR          2019-05-22 18:45:16  1.36
```

My code keeps giving me this result and I don't know how to fix it:

```
ID  RecordingType Date                 Value
1   FEVR          2019-05-22 18:45:16  1.35
```

Can you please help me? :(

P.S. I would prefer to keep the for loop, as there are multiple other if/else conditions for other recording types (I tried the groupby method but it messes up with the downstream code)

Comment: The issue with your code is that you are updating the value of the next row based on the value of the current row when they are marked for deletion. 

This is causing the next row to be updated with the old value before it is deleted, rather than the updated value.

To fix this issue, you can _update the value of the next row first_, and _then mark the current row for deletion_. This way, the next row will be updated with the correct value before it is kept, and the current row will be deleted as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

I have updated the code with your simplified data (thanks to pycharm that suggested using datetime in this code :D ):

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 1],
    'RecordingType': ['FEVR', 'FEVR', 'FEVR'],
    'Date': ['2019-05-22 18:37:10', '2019-05-22 18:41:12', '2019-05-22 18:45:16'],
    'Value': [1.36, 1.35, 1.35]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'RecordingType', 'Date'], ascending=True).reset_index().drop(columns=["index"])
df["ToRemove"] = False

outputcolnames = {'FEVR': 'Value'}

for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
    curr_recording_type = df.loc[i, "RecordingType"]
    next_recording_type = df.loc[i + 1, "RecordingType"]

    # Check if current and next row have the same ID and RecordingType and the difference in time between the current
    # and next rows is less than 60 minutes
    if df.loc[i, "ID"] == df.loc[i + 1, "ID"] and curr_recording_type == next_recording_type and abs((datetime.strptime(
            df.loc[i, "Date"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(df.loc[i + 1, "Date"],
                                                                        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds() / 60) < 60:

        # For similar rows the first row is marked for deletion and the second row's value is updated depending on
        # the Recording Type
        df.at[i, "ToRemove"] = True

        if curr_recording_type == 'FEVR':
            df.iloc[i + 1, df.columns.get_loc(outputcolnames[next_recording_type])] = max(
                df.loc[i, outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]], df.loc[i + 1, outputcolnames[next_recording_type]])
        else:
            df.iloc[i + 1, df.columns.get_loc(outputcolnames[next_recording_type])] += df.loc[
                i, outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]]

# Remove the columns to be deleted
df = df[df["ToRemove"] == False].reset_index().drop(columns=["index", "ToRemove"])

print(df)
#   ID RecordingType                 Date  Value
#0   1          FEVR  2019-05-22 18:45:16   1.36
```

hope that this will work for you

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer :) did you try running it with the sample dataset? I just tried it and it gave me the same result with 1.35 instead of 1.36. It seems like it is updating the second row, for some reason isn't updating the last row and deleting the first two rows.. Do you have any ideas why? :(

Comment: omg, worked!! thanks a lot, you are the best <3

Answer (score 0):

For this specific recording type, if your goal is to get the maximum value and associate it to the maximum date, you can do like this:

```
df.groupby("RecordiingType")[["Date", "Value"]].max()
```

You can optionally add a `.reset_index(drop=False)` if you want to get back the `RecordingType` as a column.

For the other rules you need to implement, you can check if it is possibile to translate them as "groupby-aggregate" pattern, and remember that you can also use the `apply` method with a custom defined function when grouping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion :) The question is more about why the current if condition isn't working properly - why is it updating the second row, but not the next one after that.. I can't see the issue with the code. It does work correctly with the first pair but doesn't work with the next pair in the next iteration.